# Paypal pay later not working when currency is GBP

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I have a paypal page that gives two options of funding, credit card and pay later service. When the currency is USD, the pay later button is visible and when the currency is GBP the pay later button is not visible.

The UK has pay later service but the button isnt displayed. This is the code.

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxx&currency=GBP&enable-funding=credit,card&components=messages,buttons">
</script>

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
              value: '50.00'
            }
          }]
        });
      }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>

<div
  data-pp-message
  data-pp-amount="50.00">
</div>
```

How can i display the paylater button when teh currency is GBP or EUR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with the same account, rendering the Pay Later button is specific to the country and currency of the receiving account.  GBP would likely require a UK receiver, while EUR would likely require DE or FR.

Whether the button displays or not (mostly not when the country and currency isn't a match), Pay Later offers might still be available to the payer in the normal PayPal checkout flow.